# Does any XSD edge case allow XML element content inside a text node?

Tags: xsd, xml-parsing, escaping, cdata

Does any XSD edge case allow (unescaped) XML element content inside a text node? E.g. can you put a CDATA element inside a tag defined as xs:string and have it validate (without declaring mixed content)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an element that contains a string i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid Studio 2018 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Root" type="xs:string" />
</xs:schema>
```

Then that can contain CDATA i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2018 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\Temp\XSDFile2.xsd">
    Optional Text
    <![CDATA[
        <someXmlData></someXmlData>
    ]]>
    Optional Text
</Root>
```

As this passes though some parsers it may get escaped back to this, but both are valid and equivalent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2018 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="XSDFile2.xsd">
    Optional Text
    &lt;someXmlData&gt;&lt;/someXmlData&gt;
    Optional Text
</Root>
```